# If a protection effect "doesn't remove Auras", can auras that are not cast be placed on the permanent?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

The card [Spectra Ward](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSpectra%20Ward%5d) has this ability:

> Enchanted creature gets +2/+2 and has protection from all colors. This effect doesn't remove Auras.

The rulings on the card say that you can't cast more Auras targeting the creature:

> Although Auras that are already attached to the creature aren’t affected by Spectra Ward, the enchanted creature can’t be the target of further Aura spells that have one or more colors.

But what happens if an Aura enters the battlefield some other way (from the effect of [Enduring Ideal](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bEnduring%20Ideal%5d), for example)? Can that Aura be attached to a creature with Spectra Ward already attached?

Comment: http://www.mtgsalvation.com/forums/magic-fundamentals/magic-rulings/magic-rulings-archives/566246-bruna-and-her-pants-vs-spectra-ward Looks like they had an official ruling (2nd post)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the Aura can still be attached, as long as the ability doing the attaching doesn't target or is from a colorless source.

---

Protection from a quality normally gives protection from DEBT.

- *Damaged*: Can't be damaged by a source with the stated quality.
- *Enchanted/Equiped/Fortified*: Can't be Enchanted, Equipped or Fortified by an permanent with the stated quality.
- *Blocked*: Can't be blocked by a creature with the stated quality.
- *Targeted*: Can't be targeted by a spell with the stated quality or by an ability from a source with the stated quality.

Spectra Ward's ability provides a neutered form of Protection. Auras are not prevented from Enchanting the protected permanent by the Protection provided by [Spectra Ward](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSpectra%20Ward%5d).

> 702.16m Some Auras both give the enchanted creature protection and say “this effect doesn’t remove” either that specific Aura or all Auras. This means that the specified Auras can legally enchant that creature and aren’t put into their owners’ graveyards as a state-based action. If the creature has other instances of protection from the same quality, those instances affect Auras as normal.

This means:

- You can't cast a colored Aura targeting the permanent protected by [Spectra Ward](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSpectra%20Ward%5d). (It's protected from being targeted.)
- Colored Auras already attached to the permanent won't fall off. (It's not protected from being enchanted.)
- You can attach a colored Aura the permanent protected by Spectra Ward.

  For example, [Enduring Ideal](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bEnduring%20Ideal%5d) isn't hindered by [Spectra Ward](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSpectra%20Ward%5d). (The permanent to which the Aura is being attached isn't protected from being enchanted, and the ability doesn't target.)

  For example, [Bruna, Light of Alabaster](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBruna%2c%20Light%20of%20Alabaster%5d)'s ability will still work even if it's protected by [Spectra Ward](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSpectra%20Ward%5d). (It's not protected from being enchanted, and the ability doesn't target.)

  However, [Aura Finesse](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAura%20Finesse%5d) would not be able to attach an Aura to a creature protected by [Spectra Ward](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSpectra%20Ward%5d) because the creature is protected from being targeted by Aura Finesse.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can still attach auras to it as long as they aren't being cast normally.

> **702.16m** Some Auras both give the enchanted creature protection and say “this effect doesn’t remove” either that specific Aura or all Auras. This means that **the specified Auras can legally enchant that creature** and aren’t put into their owners’ graveyards as a state-based action. If the creature has other instances of protection from the same quality, those instances affect Auras as normal.

And

> **303.4f** If an Aura is entering the battlefield under a player’s control by any means other than by resolving as an Aura spell, and the effect putting it onto the battlefield doesn’t specify the object or player the Aura will enchant, that player chooses what it will enchant as the Aura enters the battlefield. The player must choose a legal object or player according to the Aura’s enchant ability and any other applicable effects.

Also, although reminder text is not official rules text, the reminder text on Spectra Ward gives the answer:

> (It can't be blocked, targeted, or dealt damage by anything that's white, blue, black, red, or green.)

Note that it leaves out the "or enchanted" part of the reminder text that would normally encompass what protection means.

The only reason you can't cast an aura normally to attach further auras to the enchanted creature is that auras are targeted spells.

Comment: I wasn't sure that I could infer the answer from the reminder text, because the reminder text also omitted "equipped", even though the effect does in fact remove colored equipments.

Comment: @murgatroid99 I missed that!

Comment: I think it would have cleared things up if they included equipped as well in the reminder text. Maybe they should have just gone with "protection from all colors except aura permanents"

Answer (score 2):

Seems that you could attach an aura to the creature:

> 303.4f If an Aura is entering the battlefield under a player’s control by any means other than by resolving as an Aura spell, and the effect putting it onto the battlefield doesn’t specify the object or player the Aura will enchant, that player chooses what it will enchant as the Aura enters the battlefield. The player must choose a legal object or player according to the Aura’s enchant ability and any other applicable effects.

Spectra Ward's ability makes it a legal object, I'd say.